# Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

estou com diversas msg de error de :
SecureStore
Notice: Undefined index:

basicamente no meu sistema de login quando não está logado aparece esse error
no carrinho de compras qnd não tem nenhum produto aparece esse error.

(Quando tem um produto no carrinho( não aparece o error, pq tem dados na tabela do mysql)
(Quando estou logado no site também não aparece error.)

codigo:

```
<div id="logobuscar">
<div id="wrapperlogo">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logosecure.png" alt="SecureStore" height="120" width="120"></div>
<div id="buscar">   <?php
                $sessao = $_SESSION['pedido'];
                $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carrinho_temporario WHERE temporario_sessao =:ses");
                $consulta -> bindValue(':ses', $sessao);
                $consulta -> execute();
                $linhas = $consulta -> rowCount();
                ?>
                <p class="text-right "><a href="carrinho.php" class="color-white bgcolor-red font-text-light font-weight-heavy car_show">Carrinho(<?= $linhas ?>)</a></p><br>
</form></div>
</div>
</div>  


<?php
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true){
?>


       <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

        <br><br>

        <label for="password">Senha: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa pelo que eu percebi, é inicializar a sessão no PHP, pois se não fizer isso, você não vai conseguir acessar algo como $_SESSION['Alguma_Coisa'];

Aprovei para verificar os nomes das chaves das sessões.

```
<div id="logobuscar">
    <div id="wrapperlogo">
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/logosecure.png" alt="SecureStore" height="120" width="120"></div>
        <div id="buscar">   <?php
            if (!session_start())
                session_start();
            $sessao = $_SESSION['pedido'];
            $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carrinho_temporario WHERE temporario_sessao =:ses");
            $consulta->bindValue(':ses', $sessao);
            $consulta->execute();
            $linhas = $consulta->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (count($linhas) > 0) {
                $linhas = $consulta->rowCount();
                ?>
                <p class="text-right "><a href="carrinho.php" class="color-white bgcolor-red font-text-light font-weight-heavy car_show">Carrinho(<?= $linhas ?>)</a></p><br>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </form></div>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <br><br>
        <label for="password">Senha: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
        // Faz as ações de busca no banco de dados...
    } else {
        // mostra as coisas de login invalido...
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: eu já iniciei mano, ele consegue acessar de boa o problema é quando não tem nada no mysql aparece esse error: Se eu adicionar 1 item ao carrinho ele some, e fazer o login o problema do login também some.

Comment: Editei a resposta para você, para ver se serve. coloquei a contagem de linhas retornadas do mysql.

Comment: opa mano creio que isso der uma ajudada, mas acho que o problema está nessa session pedido pois deu esse error: Notice: Undefined index: pedido in C:\xampp\htdocs\skincs\logar.php on line 2

Comment: Veja a modificação na resposta em relação a $_SESSION['logged_in'], que estava sendo verifica de forma que se não existisse, retornaria erro.

Comment: crlho tu é o cara mano mds kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: eu tava desde ontem quebrando a cabeça por um negocio tão simples ...'

Comment: Isso é normal amigo, todos nós já sofremos muito um dia! Abraço e boa caminhada nos código!

Comment: será que se utilizar uma logica parecido no  $sessao = $_SESSION['pedido']; daria certo?

Comment: Sim, claro, essa é a melhor forma que conheço para testar sessões. vai fundo!

Comment: if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true){

    echo '<a href="logar.php"><li>Login</li></a>';

}else{

    echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
}
?>

Comment: vc poderia me ajudar nessa parte? Quando não está logado aparece o undefined para o username e eu não estou conseguindo utilizar essa logica nisso.

Comment: O mesmo nome que você der para o name no input do html, você recupera no post $_POST["name do input aqui"], aí depois, faz o lance do isset para saber se existe, ou !isset para saber se NÃO existe.

Comment: tem como vc mandar o codigo? Eu não entendi mt bem kk.

Comment: To montando algo aqui, mas fica atento pois você não tem username no codigo mostrado aqui, e sim email e é ele que tu recupera lá no php. vai testando aí enquanto eu faço.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83741/discussion-between-luis-alberto-batista-and-gabriel-costa).